# How to make the image translucent and change the bounds in JAVA using Eclipse Android API level 2?

Tags: overlays, eclipse-adt

I used the `HelloItemizedOverlay` code from Google to create and overlay item and it works but now I need to make the image translucent and change the bounds and I do not know how that works exactly.

I found the method `getOpacity()` but I do not know how to implement it in my `ItemizedOverlay` class or in my `Map` class. I am also aware of `getIntrinsicHeight()` and `getIntrinsicWidth()` methods but like the `getOpacity()` I do not know how to use it correctly. The code I have used for my `ItemizedOverlay` is :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class ContourItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

    Context mContext;

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

public ContourItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenter(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public int getOpacity()
{
    return PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
  return true;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlays.size();
} 

}
```

Comment: I would also like to get rid of the setMessage() because I do not need a message to appear when the image is touched but when I comment the code out the application crashed when I use the map.